# Iterative procedure naming

Tags: c++, string, loops, char

I have a process running multiple times over a picture. I would like to save each intermediate picture result using a increasing name;

Ie iteration1.png, iteration2.png, etc. The number of iterations may change between each execution.

I am having trouble creating the name.

I am using char strings and not strings for the name (thats just the way it is, I have received functions that use it like this).

How would I code the name = "iteration"+iter+".png"?

I have tried strcat, I have tried with addition (+).

My last try:
            `char name[] = strcat("result/",(char)i);
            name = strcat(name,".png");`

Thanks

Comment: We need more code, or the error you get

Comment: Try to use the current time in your filename

Comment: I added my last try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write something like:

```
std::ostringstream o;

o << "iteration" << iter << ".png";
```

, using o.str() as the filename.

Comment: This gives the correct output. However my output command does not accept it. `cvSaveImage(o.str(), image2);` give me the error _Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: int cvSaveImage(const char *, const void *, const int *) '_

Comment: o.str().c_str() should be OK if wanting to convert to C-style strings.  Just don't store the resulting pointer or do anything nefarious with it in cvSaveImage.  Also remember to either create "o" every iteration or call o.clear() otherwise it will accumulate.

Comment: This as well _ - cannot convert 'std::basic_ostringstream<char>::__string_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const 
  char*' for argument '1' to 'int cvSaveImage(const char*, const CvArr*, const int*)'_

Comment: My little repo works, "cvSaveImage(o.str().c_str(), ..."

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
const int MAX_LEN = 20;
char name[MAX_LEN + 1];
snprintf(name, MAX_LEN, "iteration%d.png", iter).
```

Comment: Probably prefer snprintf over sprintf if using C lib functions, these days at least.

Comment: by using `%03d` you could even have awesome names like: `iteration009`. This could be useful when sorting the files.